# Question on area under and between curves and volume of a solid by revolution

Tags: calculus, integration

I have recently begun learning about finding the area under the curve by definite integrals. But I am still a little unsure of the concepts. When you integrate for a certain range of the graph , does it only give you the area above the x axis , or does it give you the net area ( Area under and above the x axis) ?

Also , I noticed that if an area between 2 graphs was to be rotated about the x axis to find the volume of the solid obtained , I cannot apply the method of finding the area between graphs. I would have to separately calculate the volume obtained by rotating each graph and then subtract to get the correct volume. Why is this?

Seeking some clarification. Thanks

Comment: For areas see http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/AreaBetweenCurves.aspx , for volumes by washers (rings) see http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/VolumeWithRings.aspx , for volumes by cylindrical shells see http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/VolumeWithCylinder.aspx